# Can google sheet increment a cell each time i print the sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to make a formula or script if needed that increment my bill number each time I print the sheet.

Something like `=D2 SUMIF(D2+1,"print")`, but I don't know how to write it or if its even possible for google sheet to use print inside a formula.

I have tried some formula but I don't know what print sheet would be called in my formula for google sheet to understand it.

Comment: I'm not aware that this is possible. Let alone that "print" is just the UI name for "download this document as PDF" and technically has nothing to do with it actually being printed.

Comment: yes I know it won't be called print but I really don't know how it would be called. I thought it would be possible since I am not the only one who would do bill with google sheet.